# Counting the number of json objects, and merge it with existing json array of objects

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

In my query I have tried to do get the count(Firstname) inside the existing json with identifier name for count ,,I dont know how to do that ,,,,
Suggestion plz

**Mysql :**

```
 <?php
$json = array();
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","arun","sachin11");

$db_select = mysql_select_db('School_Database', $con);
$username = $_GET['username'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Temp_Password,Password,FirstName FROM SchoolDB where Username='$username'",$con);
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json[] = $r;
}

if($result){
$json['count'] = count($json);
   echo json_encode($json); 
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**My output:**
In my output the count displayed outside,,I want that to display inside

```
[{"FirstName":"childname2"},{"FirstName":"childname4"}]2
```

I want to add do as

```
[{"count":"2"}{"FirstName":"childname2"},{"FirstName":"childname4"}]
```

can it be done..

Comment: You should notice that `json_encode($json,count($json))` is wrong since you send a second argument to json_encode() which will understand it as a bit mask. [Read the documentation about](http://php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 0):

You should add count => 2 key-value to $json before encoding,
just like

```
if ($result) {
  $json['count'] = count($json);
  echo json_encode($json);
}
```

I think this will work for you